# The domain of $\frac{\ln x}{x}$.

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

I have to find the domain for $f(x) = \frac{\ln x}{x}$

Naturally,   $x$ must be larger than $0$ and $x$ can't be $0$ so $x > 0$.

But when I [graphed](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Graph%20f(x)%3Dln(x)%2Fx) the function, it has two "parts", one in the positive quadrant and another where $x$ is negative.
So I'm not sure how the negative part exists, if you can't put any negative numbers into log?

Also, they ask me to find where $\frac{\ln x}{x}$ cuts through $x$, so I put $\frac{\ln x}{x} = 0$ so $x =1$. But if the negative part exists, the functions also cuts the graph at $x=-1$. But we are not allowed to input $-1$ into $\log(x)$!

So, how is it possible?

Comment: Note that some branches are imaginary parts, that is, the plotter is considering it a complex function.

Comment: If you choose "Real valued plot" from the select box you'll see the graph you are referring to. W|A is assuming that $x \in \mathbb C$.